# Linear gradient for more than just CSS background?

Tags: html, css

It is possible to specify `linear-gradient` for the `background` or `background-image` CSS properties. Is it also possible to do so for the object as a whole, including borders, outline, etc.? Or a filter that does the same?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is For `border gradient`..

```css
.ps-top-to-bottom {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
}
.ps-top-to-bottom:before, .ps-top-to-bottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#000), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#000, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#000, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#000, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000, transparent);
  top: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  width: 3px;
}
.ps-top-to-bottom:before {
  left: -3px;
}
.ps-top-to-bottom:after {
  right: -3px;
}
```

```html
<!-- THIS IS FOR BORDER-->
<div class="ps-top-to-bottom">
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: The borders don't line up properly in Chrome, but this is a good answer because it is a pure CSS solution. Another solution I read about is using SVG filters in HTML, though I haven't tested it yet (and it is not pure CSS obviously.)

Comment: if you need SVG filters than click on this link [http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_fegaussianblur.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_fegaussianblur.asp) you will get all information

Answer (score -1):

```css
#grad {
    background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<div id="grad">hola mundo</div>
```

and result is:
[image]

Comment: This only works for the background property. I'm looking for something that also applies to borders, outlines, etc. I.e. the whole container.